# A good account of the development of the modern fantasy genre?

Tags: history, fantasy-genre

I am looking for a good account for the development of modern fantasy, [something like this section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_fantasy#Post-Tolkien_fantasy), just bigger and covering newer authors like GRRM or Glen Cook (you know an article is outdated when you have to call those two new). A book would also be fine (if it's in print).

In case people don't understand what I am asking: I want to know why the books we read today are the way they are? For example, why are there stock race like elves, dwarves in some books? Was this solely because of LoTR or maybe the success of D&D board games contributed to this? When did fantasy begin publishing "dark" works (like ASoIaF)? Was GRRM's success a pathbreaker that allowed writers like Bakker and Abercrombie? Did the boom in sci-fi TV shows and movies in the 70s influence fantasy writing in any way? Is Ursula LeGuin's nearly as influential as it is made out to be?

I am pretty sure somebody would have written articles/books on this subject. I am looking for people to forward me to some such article/book.

Comment: This seems to me like a recommendation question. Can you clarify the question so it is not one? Also, let's not try to get around the banned fantasy tag. :)

Comment: I think the linked article does a good job of explaining what I want - A list of pathbreaking works/events, that influenced authors down the years. Basically things that explain that why the books we read today are the way they are.

Comment: @DampeS8N: I have requested an unban on the fantasy tag at http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/507/ban-on-sci-fi-and-fantasy-tags

Comment: Wouldn't the right course of action be to update the wikipedia entry?

Comment: @DampeS8N:I would if I had data/sources. You are not supposed to present your own views on subjective matters in wikipedia articles, all research must come from reputable sources.

Comment: Amazon searches do land somewhat promising results http://www.amazon.com/Short-History-Fantasy-Popular-culture/dp/1904750680/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303930803&sr=8-1

Comment: This is sort of a story-identification question, but instead of looking for a specific story, you're looking for a type of reference book/encyclopedia.

Comment: Isn't the on-topic, non-thinly-veiled-recommendation-question version of this just to *ask the site directly* a question about what you're trying to understand? That's the whole point of this site.

Comment: @Mark:I fail to understand why people think this is a recommendation question. Of course such a question cannot be answered without naming important books in the genre (thus making it a list instead of recommendation question), but I don't want to read the books, I want to understand how they affected the genre. Reading LoTR doesn't tell me that Tolkien basically reinvented the elves and made a race that would be eventually be used by thousands of other authors.

Comment: @Mark: Considering the scope, asking someone to post a good account of the modern fantasy genre as an answer would be wildly disproportionate. This question is like “What are good books to learn C programming”, you wouldn't ask someone to write the book contents.

Comment: @Gilles asking people to provide a general account of anything is wildly off-topic, and asking for book recommendations doesn't change that. If there's a *specific* question that needs answering, *that's* what Stack Exchange is good at, not generating lists of recommendations. To wit, the C programming book question is off-topic on both SO and Programmers.

Comment: @Mark: This comment thread is too long already. If you don't like this question, raise the issue on Meta.

Comment: You mean, fantasy still exists? I thought Tolkien more or less killed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found some good articles on the net -

- [History of Fantasy](http://www.thecheers.org/Entertainment/article_23_The-History-of-Fantasy.html) on thecheers.org
- [The history of fantasy throughout the world](http://library.thinkquest.org/C003239/historyindex.html) on thinkquest.org
- [Brief history of fantasy](http://home.austarnet.com.au/petersykes/fantasy100/admin_history.html) on austarnet.com.au

These are all very brief, few paras each but still good enough reads.

The best result so far was the summary of a book ["A Short History of Fantasy"](http://www.thingsmeanalot.com/2010/04/short-history-of-fantasy-by-farah.html) by Farah Mendlesohn and Edward James. From its [amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1904750680), a brief look inside the book's content seems promising. A little expensive, but I will treat myself.

There's also a pretty large and complicated picture [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110315035008/http://scimaps.org/submissions/7-digital_libraries/maps/thumbs/024_LG.jpg), which seems to be a timeline of works in the fantasy genre.

A good article that discusses recent dark trends in fantasy is [The Fantasy Genre, a brief history and its highlights](http://edbutkin.tumblr.com/post/212509593/the-fantasy-genre-a-brief-history-and-its-highlights) at [edbutkin's blog](http://edbutkin.tumblr.com/).

A book that showed several times in search results was "The Secret History of Fantasy"  edited by Peter S. Beagle. It's not exactly a discussion of the fantasy genre, but seems interesting. You can read its [review by Strange Horizons](http://www.strangehorizons.com/reviews/2011/04/the_secret_hist.shtml).

Comment: Also well worth reading is J.R.R. Tolkien's classic "On Fairy Stories".

Comment: Many links are dead now, unfortunately :-(

Comment: love that picture, even with the spelling mistakes